# how to redirect to another action on mvc controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application has the following Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("dealer"))
    {
        return View(db.Commissions.Where(c => c.Dealer.Name == User.Identity.Name));
    }
    else
    {//admin
        return View(db.Commissions);
    }
}
```

I would like to redirect my page to another mvc action called filter but cant get it done with this code:

```
   $(function () {
        jQuery.noConflict()
        $("#datefrom").datepicker();
        $("#dateto").datepicker();

        $("#btnfilter").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/commissions/filter/",
                data:{'from':$("#datefrom").val(),to:$("#dateto").val()}
                ,success: function(result){
                    if(result.Success){
                        window.location = "/Filter/Commissions" + $("#datefrom").val() + $("#dateto").val();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

this is the filter action:

```
 public ActionResult Filter(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("dealer"))
            {
                return View(db.Commissions.Where(c => c.Dealer.Name == User.Identity.Name && c.CreatedDate>=from && c.CreatedDate <=to));
            }
            else

            {//admin
                var test = db.Commissions.Where(c => c.CreatedDate >= from && c.CreatedDate <= to);
                return View(db.Commissions.Where(c=>c.CreatedDate >= from && c.CreatedDate <= to));
            }
        }
```

The filter action is hit on the server but I get the following error when i look in the fiddler:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view 'filter' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does the view file Filter.cshtml exist?

Comment: I think, on success of ajax call, you are passing wrong url. Instead of "/Filter/Commissions", have to use "/Commissions/Filter"

Answer (score 0):

Try as this, but I have one doubt in your code where you are returning `true/false` in filter action.

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.noConflict()
    $("#datefrom").datepicker();
    $("#dateto").datepicker();

    $("#btnfilter").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("filter","commissions")',
            data:{'from':$("#datefrom").val(),to:$("#dateto").val()},
            success: function(result){
                if(result.Success){
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("filter","commissions",new{from=$("#datefrom").val(),to=$("#dateto").val()})';
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: the filter action is hit that is not the issue

Comment: Then what is yr problem?

Comment: the result does not get updated ie the results dont get filtered